# How can i get file name without extension via regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to add alt description of image when there is none via regex, but furthest I got was extracting the file name with the extension.

The problem is with extracting only file name from src of the image without any extension and put it as alt text of image.

Furthest i got within code is:
`/(<img.*?)(src=")(.*?\/)([^\/]*")(.*?)(alt=")(.*?")([^>]*>)/`

with example of:
`<img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-18" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/300x149-jquerymobile.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="149">`

Have been workin on:
[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/s9AiKl/1)

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex.

Comment: Can you please give me the pattern of output for more understanding

Comment: The result should look like this: <img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-18" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/300x149-jquerymobile.jpg" alt="300x149-jquerymobile" width="300" height="149">

Comment: Or simply: 300x139-jquerymobile

Comment: This would be trivial to do with a DOM parser and `pathinfo()`. Is there a real need to use regular expressions? I mean, does it need to integrate with some library or tool that only accepts regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write the pattern like this:

```
(<img\b[^<>]*\bsrc="[^\s"]*/([^\s]+)\.\w+")([^<>]*\balt=")("[^<>]*>)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wVYH2a/1)

And replace using the capture groups with:

```
$1$3$2$4
```

Note that this will only work if the src comes before the alt.

A better option is using a dom parser / DOMDocument, then get the src value and extract the  image name without the extension.

Then set that to the alt value.